# How to handle cases in software when you cant handle it by events?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm in a situation where i should handle cases when there is no event happened.

I have an entity called `Subscribe` which is a subscribe plan. There is a property on it called `ExpireDate` and when it's passed i want to set it's status to ended and send a notification to user that your subscribe plan is deleted. I have no idea how should i handle this case.

I mean there is no event that could happen and i check this condition in it.

I'm using asp.net core with `mongodb` if it matters.

I'm beginner so maybe it is a simple question but i'm actually lost :D.

Comment: Do you want to solve this on asp.net side or in mongodb side?

Comment: do you know about polling? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)

Comment: @pevecg doesnt matter i think but asp side would be better

Comment: @NimaMaskani You can make a timer in Asp.net then that checks all users and sees if their ExpiredDate has passed. How often is up to you. Does it matter if its 1-60 minutes late?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a batch process running daily and checking for that condition and creating and event by sending a message with the expiration details to a message queue, or directly writing the notification (this is the worse option as it's coupling both processes.)

Comment: so this process or anything that is like this is that hard to handle ?

Comment: On almost every business you have this kind of batching processes, it's very common. My advice is to keep it away from your asp.net code, as batch and web have different ways of operate. Take a look at http://topshelf-project.com/ and https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/, with a mix of it you may achieve your goal

Comment: Yeah, i came to a conclusion that i will create a windows service and run a script every day to check what i need it to do. Thanks for your reply and time.